# sql WHERE Id = 'x' or IN (x) or a field

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I have an issue querying my Database, i have 2 tables, users table with column `id, name, phone, email, phone, password, account_number, bank, status and assignedId`.
the second table is paired table which contains column `id, name, phone, assignedId`. the both has an id with autocrement as primary key.the values are assigned in the two tables during registration

i have registered some accounts on my `localhost phpmyadmin` therefore some `id` has automatically been inserted with other values except `assignedId` field value, i have manually inputted into my `assignedId` field a number `4` in the users table which is among one of the auto-generated id in my id column in the database, my issue is that i want to select `name`, `phone` from my second table using any number inputted in the diffrerent rows in the `assignedId` field, for example, i manually inputted a number (4) in my `assignedId`field as the id whose details is to be selected, so that when ever the user who bears the row values where the `assignedId` field is filled with a value e.g 4 is `logged_in` he sees the values of the user whose id has been inserted into his `assignedId` field, but the problem there is that, instead of only one user who has the row in which an id is inserted into his `assignedId` to see the values selected, every member that is registered is seeing the values, please help, i have the below code

---

```
 sql = "SELECT paired.name, paired.phone FROM paired INNER JOIN users ON paired.id = users.assigedId"
 $sql =SELECT paired.name, paired.phone
 FROM paired
 INNER JOIN users
 ON paired.id=users.assignedId;
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: you are missing condition `WHERE users.id=logged_in_user_id`... example `WHERE users.id=4`

Comment: Please write how u think it should look like using the code I wrote,  please

Comment: example `SELECT paired.name, paired.phone FROM paired INNER JOIN users ON paired.id = users.assigedId WHERE users.id=4`

Comment: Assuming there is another user,  do I also have to paste these code again and change the ID to be 5 or something, like every new user,  it will be like users.id=5, users.id=6 continuesly?